# Hard drive error - NTFS damaged

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, ntfs, system-recovery

I am helping a friend recover data from a computer (lenovo). After what I was told was a hard shutdown, the computer does not get past the system repair screen. (Windows failed to start)

Booting off a live CD (linux), i tried mounting the drive to read the data off of it.

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 12: Failed to read last sector (1497614767): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

I tried force mounting it:

```
    root@lubuntu:/media/external# ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/external -o force
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0xd0f0210c  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 57365  usa_count: 3891: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0xd0f0210c)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

I also tried running "chkdsk D: \r" and "chkdsk D: \f" from the command prompt I am allowed to use when the dialogue for what to do during the boot process comes up (it offers system repair as one of the options, as well as cmd). I rebooted and the drive is still not mountable.

Then I tried running ntfsfix:

```
    root@lubuntu:/media/external# ntfsfix /dev/sdb
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
root@lubuntu:/media/external#
```

sdb1:

```
root@lubuntu:/media/external# ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
Mounting volume... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0xd0f0210c  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 57365  usa_count: 3891: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0xd0f0210c)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0xd0f0210c  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 57365  usa_count: 3891: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0xd0f0210c)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Input/output error
Checking for self-located MFT segment... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0xd0f0210c  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 57365  usa_count: 3891: Invalid argument
OK
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0xd0f0210c  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 57365  usa_count: 3891: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0xd0f0210c)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

gparted:

[image]
[image]
[image]

What should I do?

Comment: The first thing I would do is duplicate the hdd to avoid additional data loss.  I would then use https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm‎ and you **MIGHT** be able to resolve the problem.  Its not clear what the result of `chkdisk` on the partition was.  Furthermore why are you using `/f` if its not a software RAID?

Comment: what flags should I run chkdsk with? ill be sure to post pictures if that will help you help me...

Comment: mainly **chkdsk /R c:**  Note:  Chances are you need a new hard drive.  chkdsk does not really fix this kind of problem it just hides the bad sectors so they are never used again.  The drive will may seem fine afterward, but eventually the hdd will fail.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) for Data Recovery or try to fix the partition. It's mainly for data recovery (in case you can't get it to work again) or you could use it for trouble shooting.

Comment: As the post was from 2013, the machine is probably either repaired or dead by now...

Comment: @SolarMike, my answer was also from 2013, though a few months later.